# DaVinci Resolve: Difference between adjusting Y or YRGB

Tags: davinci-resolve, color-grading

In DaVinci Resolve 14, some operations can be performed on all of the Y, R, G, B channels at the same time or only on one of them.

What is the difference between adjusting only Y, or adjusting all of YRGB?  The effect looks the same.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My statement that the effect looks the same was incorrect. The use of these sliders is explained in the manual, in "Primary Grading Controls" -> "Color Wheels Palette" -> "RGB Lift/Gamma/Gain Sliders" (page 725 in the v14 manual).  Quoting:

> ... These three controls allow easy Y-only adjustments to contrast, where an increase in contrast results in perceptually diminished color saturation.
>
> Making Y-only adjustments to contrast is a great way to increase contrast when you’re going for muted saturation or a gritty look. This kind of adjustment is also useful in situations where you’re trying to increase shadow density without increasing image colorfulness.

Comment: Glad you found it.  I knew the description of it doing the same thing was wrong from experience, but didn't have the manual handy to double check exactly what the difference was.